# PHP Setting Correct Time Zone

Tags: php, timezone

I have the following code

`date("D j M g a", strtotime($start))." - " . date("ga", strtotime($finish));`

```
`["Start"]=>
        string(21) "/Date(1354323600000)/"
        ["End"]=>
        string(21) "/Date(1354326300000)/"
      }`
```

The above code outputs `Thu 1 Jan 12 pm - 12pm" string(22) "Thu 1 Jan 12 pm - 12pm` in the correct format that I want but how could I get the day date and time correct.

`Pacific/Auckland` is my timezone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that what you pass to the `strtotime` - `/Date(1354323600000)/` string is not in a valid format for `strtotime` function.

And actually it's a regular unix timestamp in milliseconds.

So the obvious solution - is to clean up everything but numbers and divide it by 1000:

```
$unix_time_with_ms = preg_replace('~\D~', '', $date);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unix_time_with_ms / 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer setting default timezone in your `php.ini` file with a line like this:

```
date.timezone = "Pacific/Auckland"
```

If for some reason you can't edit `php.ini` then on top of your PHP script you can set a timezone (effective for that script only):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Pacific/Auckland');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set time zone using

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

More [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set in the script try

`date_default_timezone_set` — Sets the default timezone used by all date/time functions in a script

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

but if you want to use the same time zone than  setting in php.ini will be better solution

```
 date.timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"
```